# How to produce scatterplot with a factor as y in highcharter?

Tags: r, highcharts, data-visualization, r-highcharter

*Problem:*

I would like to produce a scatter plot with `highcharter::hchart`, where `y` is a `factor`, and x is a `date`.

Apparently, **`highcharter::hchart` `"scatter"` does not accept factor variables as y.**

Is there any workaround?
Or is `"scatter"` just the wrong charttype?

*(Comment: I know `ggplotly` would be a good alternative, but I actually need a `highcharter` solution)*

---

*Example:*

Let's suppose I want to produce a **timeline of publications by type**.
I want a scatterplot with `d$type` (=y-axis) and `d$date` (=x-axis) and the `highcharter` tooltip should show me `d$title`, `d$type` and `d$date` (properly formatted).

```
library(stringi)
library(tidyverse)
library(highcharter)

### create example data
d <- data.frame(date = sample(seq(as.Date("2001/1/1"),
                                  as.Date("2003/1/1"),
                                  by = "day"),
                              30), # Date of publication
                title = stringi::stri_rand_strings(30, 5), # Title of publication
                type = rep(c("book","article","tweet"),
                           length.out=30)) # Publication type
glimpse(d)
#>Observations: 30
#>Variables: 3
#>$ date  <date> 2001-02-21, 2001-12-31, 2002-09-02, 2002-12-11, 2001-...
#>$ title <fct> NvHuI, 81HoS, TsyWs, KbTT2, I2p4f, ASasv, HuclA, cmihb...
#>$ type  <fct> book, article, tweet, book, article, tweet, book, arti...


### ggplot2: static plot
ggplot(d, aes(x=date,
              y=type)) +
  geom_point(aes(colour=type), 
             alpha=0.5,
             size = 3) + 
  scale_x_date(date_labels = "%m / %Y") +
  theme_light() +
  theme(panel.grid.minor.x = element_blank())
```

[image: ggplot]

`ggplot2::geom_points` does a nice job here.

However, I want the chart to be interactive (tooltip showing the title and so on...) So I'll give it a try with `highcharter::hchart`:

```
### highcharter: interactive plot
# A.) NOT WORKING, because y is a factor
hchart(d,
       "scatter",
       hcaes(x = date,
             y = type,
             group = type))
```

Apparently, `highcharter::hchart "scatter"` doesn't accept a `factor` as `y`.

The only way I get this working is transforming `d$type` to numeric...but then the `xAxisLabels` and the tooltip are wrong...

```
# B.) WORKING, because y is numeric
hchart((d %>% 
          mutate(typenum = as.numeric(type))), 
       "scatter",
       hcaes(x = date,
             y = typenum,
             group = typenum))
```

[image: hchart]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An alternative would be:

```
lvls <- d %>% pull(type) %>% levels()

d %>% 
  mutate(typenum = as.numeric(type) - 1) %>% 
  hchart("scatter", hcaes(x = date, y = typenum, group = type)) %>% 
  hc_yAxis(categories = lvls)
```

[image]

Note the `as.numeric(type) - 1`, this is beacause Javascript and then highcharts is 0-index. So when we add the name of categories, highcharts will start with 0.

Comment: Great answer, great package by the way @jbkunst, you're the best!