# Is it possible use size (z) argument with RHighcharter and a categorical Y-axis?

Tags: r, highcharts

> **Objective**: Highchart with categorial y-axis and size argument.  The points (bubbles) should be change size according an argument.

```
library(dplyr)
library(highcharter)

lvl <- iris %>% pull(Species) %>% levels()

iris %>% mutate(typenum = as.numeric(Species) - 1) -> iris2
```

*Works:*

```
highchart() %>%
  hc_add_series(iris2,'scatter',hcaes(x = Sepal.Length, y = typenum)) %>%
  hc_yAxis(categories = lvl)
```

[image]

*Does not work:*

It seems the use of size argument throws off the categorical Y-axis.  Note the additional unwanted categories of `3` and `-1`.

```
highchart() %>%
  hc_add_series(iris2,'scatter',hcaes(x = Sepal.Length, y = typenum, z=Petal.Width)) %>%
  hc_yAxis(categories = lvl)
```

[image]

How can I use the size (z) argument with highcharter in R and a categorical Y-axis?

Related: [How to produce scatterplot with a factor as y in highcharter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49034106/how-to-produce-scatterplot-with-a-factor-as-y-in-highcharter/49035633#49035633)

Comment: Your question is not understandable to me ! Can you explain with example?

Comment: @AnkurSingh Added a bit more detail.  The graph should look like the second one shown, except without the -1 and 3 categories.

Comment: Hi Minnow, I reproduced your problem in basic JS code. Highcharts reserve additional space for bubbles, you can avoid that by setting min and max for yAxis: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/sht4fzu3/

Comment: @ppotaczek Thanks, that worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Highcharts reserve additional space for bubbles, you can avoid that by setting **min** and **max** for yAxis:

```
yAxis: {
    type: 'category',
    min: 0,
    max: 2
}
```

Live demo: jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/sht4fzu3