# Highcharter Dot Plots

Tags: r, r-highcharter

I'm trying to make the below dotplot in highcharter using R.
[dotplot example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eAvVj.png)

I'm able to do it in ggplot (as shown in the figure) and make it interactive using ggplotly() but I can't seem to replicate it in highcharter. Below is the code I used to make the above figure.

```
ggplot(mapping = aes(x= sample_id_collect, y=expanded_predicted_cell_type)) +
  geom_point(data = df.final, aes(color=subject_id, size = mean_expression_ratio)) + 
  theme_cowplot() +
  background_grid() +
  theme(axis.title.x = element_blank(), axis.title.y = element_blank(), axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust=1)) +
  guides(size = guide_legend(title = '% Cells Expressing Gene'))
```

The dataframe df.final looks like this:

```
    sample_id_collect        score subject_id expanded_predicted_cell_type mean_expression_ratio
1           Donor-2-A  0.794472286    Donor-2          AXL+ Dendritic Cell            0.50000000
2           Donor-2-B  0.591766012    Donor-2          AXL+ Dendritic Cell            0.31481482
3           Donor-4-A  0.230889532    Donor-4          AXL+ Dendritic Cell            0.16666667
4           Donor-1-A  0.000000000    Donor-1          AXL+ Dendritic Cell            0.00000000
5           Donor-1-B  0.000000000    Donor-1          AXL+ Dendritic Cell            0.00000000
```

When I try this in highcharter I get a blank view.

```
hchart(df.final, "scatter", 
       hcaes(x=sample_id_collect, y=expanded_predicted_cell_type, size=mean_expression_ratio, group = subject_id))
```

If anyone knows or has an idea please share.
Thanks!

Comment: As you want categorical variables both on the x and y axis maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49034106/how-to-produce-scatterplot-with-a-factor-as-y-in-highcharter helps to answer your question.

Comment: @stefan, yeah that didn't work for me I got NAs for some reason and couldn't work around it.

Comment: Have you converted your column `expanded_predicted_cell_type` to a `factor`? I did that and it worked for me. However, I ran in an issue with the axis breaks.

Comment: Yup, made that column a factor and still got a blank view, no graph.

Comment: I ended up doing this in plotly as shown in the below link but couldn't get rid of the extra colorbar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71132445/r-plotly-remove-specific-colorbar