# R-plotly remove specific colorbar

Tags: r, r-plotly

I've been trying to make R-plotly display both a colorbar and a legend for a while and finally got it to work. However, the plot also displays a second colorbar (see picture with colorbar labeled "score") which I do not want. I haven't been able to remove this other colorbar. If anyone knows a workaround or an alternative to the code below, please help.

My code:

```
# dataframe used
structure(list(samples = c("Donor-3-treat_3", "Donor-1-Unstim", 
"Donor-4-Unstim", "Donor-1-treat_1", "Donor-4-treat_1", "Donor-1-treat_2", 
"Donor-4-treat_2", "Donor-1-treat_3", "Donor-4-treat_3", "Donor-2-Unstim", 
"Donor-2-treat_1", "Donor-2-treat_2", "Donor-2-treat_3", "Donor-3-Unstim", 
"Donor-3-treat_1", "Donor-3-treat_2", "Donor-1-Unstim", "Donor-1-treat_1", 
"Donor-3-treat_1", "Donor-4-Unstim", "Donor-1-treat_3", "Donor-1-treat_2", 
"Donor-2-treat_1", "Donor-2-treat_3", "Donor-2-treat_2", "Donor-2-Unstim", 
"Donor-3-treat_3", "Donor-3-treat_2", "Donor-3-Unstim", "Donor-4-treat_1", 
"Donor-4-treat_3", "Donor-4-treat_2", "Donor-4-Unstim", "Donor-2-treat_1", 
"Donor-4-treat_1", "Donor-3-Unstim", "Donor-4-treat_2", "Donor-3-treat_1", 
"Donor-1-Unstim", "Donor-1-treat_1", "Donor-2-Unstim", "Donor-3-treat_2", 
"Donor-4-treat_3", "Donor-2-treat_2", "Donor-1-treat_3", "Donor-1-treat_2", 
"Donor-2-treat_3", "Donor-3-treat_3", "Donor-3-treat_2", "Donor-1-treat_1", 
"Donor-3-treat_3", "Donor-1-treat_2", "Donor-4-Unstim", "Donor-2-Unstim", 
"Donor-4-treat_1", "Donor-2-treat_1", "Donor-4-treat_2", "Donor-2-treat_2", 
"Donor-3-Unstim", "Donor-3-treat_1", "Donor-4-treat_3", "Donor-1-Unstim", 
"Donor-1-treat_3", "Donor-2-treat_3", "Donor-3-treat_2", "Donor-2-treat_1", 
"Donor-3-treat_3", "Donor-2-treat_2", "Donor-4-treat_1", "Donor-2-treat_3", 
"Donor-4-treat_2", "Donor-3-treat_1", "Donor-4-treat_3", "Donor-1-treat_1", 
"Donor-1-treat_2", "Donor-1-treat_3", "Donor-1-Unstim", "Donor-2-Unstim", 
"Donor-3-Unstim", "Donor-4-Unstim", "Donor-2-treat_1", "Donor-1-Unstim", 
"Donor-3-Unstim", "Donor-1-treat_1", "Donor-3-treat_1", "Donor-1-treat_2", 
"Donor-3-treat_3", "Donor-4-Unstim", "Donor-4-treat_1", "Donor-4-treat_2", 
"Donor-4-treat_3", "Donor-2-treat_2", "Donor-2-treat_3", "Donor-1-treat_3", 
"Donor-2-Unstim", "Donor-3-treat_2", "Donor-4-treat_3", "Donor-3-treat_2", 
"Donor-1-Unstim", "Donor-3-treat_3", "Donor-1-treat_1", "Donor-4-Unstim", 
"Donor-1-treat_2", "Donor-4-treat_1", "Donor-1-treat_3", "Donor-4-treat_2", 
"Donor-2-Unstim", "Donor-2-treat_1", "Donor-2-treat_2", "Donor-2-treat_3", 
"Donor-3-Unstim", "Donor-3-treat_1", "Donor-2-treat_1", "Donor-1-treat_1", 
"Donor-2-treat_2", "Donor-1-treat_2", "Donor-2-treat_3", "Donor-1-treat_3", 
"Donor-3-treat_1", "Donor-2-Unstim", "Donor-3-treat_3", "Donor-4-treat_3", 
"Donor-4-treat_1", "Donor-4-treat_2", "Donor-1-Unstim", "Donor-3-Unstim", 
"Donor-3-treat_2", "Donor-4-Unstim", "Donor-2-treat_1", "Donor-3-treat_2", 
"Donor-2-treat_2", "Donor-3-treat_3", "Donor-2-treat_3", "Donor-4-treat_1", 
"Donor-3-treat_1", "Donor-4-treat_2", "Donor-4-treat_3", "Donor-1-treat_1", 
"Donor-1-treat_2", "Donor-1-treat_3", "Donor-1-Unstim", "Donor-2-Unstim", 
"Donor-3-Unstim", "Donor-4-Unstim", "Donor-2-Unstim", "Donor-4-Unstim", 
"Donor-4-treat_3", "Donor-2-treat_2", "Donor-2-treat_3", "Donor-3-treat_1", 
"Donor-4-treat_1", "Donor-2-treat_1", "Donor-3-treat_3", "Donor-4-treat_2", 
"Donor-3-Unstim", "Donor-1-Unstim", "Donor-1-treat_1", "Donor-1-treat_3", 
"Donor-1-treat_2", "Donor-3-treat_2", "Donor-2-Unstim", "Donor-3-treat_2", 
"Donor-2-treat_1", "Donor-3-treat_3", "Donor-2-treat_2", "Donor-4-Unstim", 
"Donor-2-treat_3", "Donor-4-treat_1", "Donor-3-treat_1", "Donor-4-treat_2", 
"Donor-4-treat_3", "Donor-1-Unstim", "Donor-1-treat_1", "Donor-1-treat_2", 
"Donor-3-Unstim", "Donor-1-treat_3", "Donor-2-treat_3", "Donor-3-treat_2", 
"Donor-3-Unstim", "Donor-4-Unstim", "Donor-3-treat_1", "Donor-4-treat_1", 
"Donor-1-Unstim", "Donor-4-treat_3", "Donor-1-treat_1", "Donor-1-treat_2", 
"Donor-1-treat_3", "Donor-2-Unstim", "Donor-3-treat_3", "Donor-4-treat_2", 
"Donor-2-treat_1", "Donor-2-treat_2"), score = c(0.182, -0.213, 
-0.213, -0.213, -0.095, 0.281, 0.329, 0.276, 0.279, -0.213, -0.213, 
0.242, 0.347, -0.213, -0.213, 0.231, 0.185, 0.353, 0.218, 0.21, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.104, 0, 0, 0.488, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0.508, 1.279, 0.444, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.229, 0, 0.224, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0.228, 0.245, 0, 0, 0.222, 0, 0.233, 0.246, 0.17, 
-0.011, 0.245, 0.458, -0.103, 0.51, 0.571, -0.163, 0.366, -0.071, 
0.18, 0.234, -0.39, -0.39, -0.39, -0.39, 0.006, -0.205, -0.205, 
-0.205, -0.205, 0.554, 0.546, -0.205, -0.006, 0.182, 0.434, 0.273, 
0.302, 0.287, -0.205, 0.261, 0.497, 0.463, -0.657, 0.432, -0.336, 
-0.747, 0.555, -0.248, 0.483, 0.446, -0.747, -0.212, 0.567, 0.744, 
-0.747, -0.565, -0.19, -0.19, 0.174, 0.228, 0.191, 0.252, -0.19, 
-0.19, 0.161, 0.355, -0.045, 0.16, -0.19, -0.19, 0.097, -0.19, 
0.054, 0.309, 0.346, 0.431, 0.548, -0.265, -0.212, 0.435, 0.549, 
-0.426, 0.431, 0.178, -0.758, -0.758, -0.758, -0.758, 0, 0, 0.423, 
0.323, 0.202, 0, 0, 0.129, 0.73, 0.228, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -0.866, 
0.752, -0.165, 0.267, 0.793, -0.866, 0.636, -0.28, -0.631, 0.785, 
0.794, -0.655, -0.401, 0.546, -0.866, 0.585, 0.17, 0.129, -0.075, 
0.058, -0.075, -0.075, -0.075, 0.13, -0.075, 0.29, 0.34, -0.075, 
0.133, 0.174, -0.075, 0.176), treatment = c("treat_3", "untreated", 
"untreated", "treat_1", "treat_1", "treat_2", "treat_2", "treat_3", 
"treat_3", "untreated", "treat_1", "treat_2", "treat_3", "untreated", 
"treat_1", "treat_2", "untreated", "treat_1", "treat_1", "untreated", 
"treat_3", "treat_2", "treat_1", "treat_3", "treat_2", "untreated", 
"treat_3", "treat_2", "untreated", "treat_1", "treat_3", "treat_2", 
"untreated", "treat_1", "treat_1", "untreated", "treat_2", "treat_1", 
"untreated", "treat_1", "untreated", "treat_2", "treat_3", "treat_2", 
"treat_3", "treat_2", "treat_3", "treat_3", "treat_2", "treat_1", 
"treat_3", "treat_2", "untreated", "untreated", "treat_1", "treat_1", 
"treat_2", "treat_2", "untreated", "treat_1", "treat_3", "untreated", 
"treat_3", "treat_3", "treat_2", "treat_1", "treat_3", "treat_2", 
"treat_1", "treat_3", "treat_2", "treat_1", "treat_3", "treat_1", 
"treat_2", "treat_3", "untreated", "untreated", "untreated", 
"untreated", "treat_1", "untreated", "untreated", "treat_1", 
"treat_1", "treat_2", "treat_3", "untreated", "treat_1", "treat_2", 
"treat_3", "treat_2", "treat_3", "treat_3", "untreated", "treat_2", 
"treat_3", "treat_2", "untreated", "treat_3", "treat_1", "untreated", 
"treat_2", "treat_1", "treat_3", "treat_2", "untreated", "treat_1", 
"treat_2", "treat_3", "untreated", "treat_1", "treat_1", "treat_1", 
"treat_2", "treat_2", "treat_3", "treat_3", "treat_1", "untreated", 
"treat_3", "treat_3", "treat_1", "treat_2", "untreated", "untreated", 
"treat_2", "untreated", "treat_1", "treat_2", "treat_2", "treat_3", 
"treat_3", "treat_1", "treat_1", "treat_2", "treat_3", "treat_1", 
"treat_2", "treat_3", "untreated", "untreated", "untreated", 
"untreated", "untreated", "untreated", "treat_3", "treat_2", 
"treat_3", "treat_1", "treat_1", "treat_1", "treat_3", "treat_2", 
"untreated", "untreated", "treat_1", "treat_3", "treat_2", "treat_2", 
"untreated", "treat_2", "treat_1", "treat_3", "treat_2", "untreated", 
"treat_3", "treat_1", "treat_1", "treat_2", "treat_3", "untreated", 
"treat_1", "treat_2", "untreated", "treat_3", "treat_3", "treat_2", 
"untreated", "untreated", "treat_1", "treat_1", "untreated", 
"treat_3", "treat_1", "treat_2", "treat_3", "untreated", "treat_3", 
"treat_2", "treat_1", "treat_2"), celltype = c("CD4+ Central Memory T", 
"CD4+ Central Memory T", "CD4+ Central Memory T", "CD4+ Central Memory T", 
"CD4+ Central Memory T", "CD4+ Central Memory T", "CD4+ Central Memory T", 
"CD4+ Central Memory T", "CD4+ Central Memory T", "CD4+ Central Memory T", 
"CD4+ Central Memory T", "CD4+ Central Memory T", "CD4+ Central Memory T", 
"CD4+ Central Memory T", "CD4+ Central Memory T", "CD4+ Central Memory T", 
"CD4+ Cytotoxic T", "CD4+ Cytotoxic T", "CD4+ Cytotoxic T", "CD4+ Cytotoxic T", 
"CD4+ Cytotoxic T", "CD4+ Cytotoxic T", "CD4+ Cytotoxic T", "CD4+ Cytotoxic T", 
"CD4+ Cytotoxic T", "CD4+ Cytotoxic T", "CD4+ Cytotoxic T", "CD4+ Cytotoxic T", 
"CD4+ Cytotoxic T", "CD4+ Cytotoxic T", "CD4+ Cytotoxic T", "CD4+ Cytotoxic T", 
"CD4+ Effector Memory T", "CD4+ Effector Memory T", "CD4+ Effector Memory T", 
"CD4+ Effector Memory T", "CD4+ Effector Memory T", "CD4+ Effector Memory T", 
"CD4+ Effector Memory T", "CD4+ Effector Memory T", "CD4+ Effector Memory T", 
"CD4+ Effector Memory T", "CD4+ Effector Memory T", "CD4+ Effector Memory T", 
"CD4+ Effector Memory T", "CD4+ Effector Memory T", "CD4+ Effector Memory T", 
"CD4+ Effector Memory T", "CD4+ Naive T", "CD4+ Naive T", "CD4+ Naive T", 
"CD4+ Naive T", "CD4+ Naive T", "CD4+ Naive T", "CD4+ Naive T", 
"CD4+ Naive T", "CD4+ Naive T", "CD4+ Naive T", "CD4+ Naive T", 
"CD4+ Naive T", "CD4+ Naive T", "CD4+ Naive T", "CD4+ Naive T", 
"CD4+ Naive T", "CD4+ Proliferating T", "CD4+ Proliferating T", 
"CD4+ Proliferating T", "CD4+ Proliferating T", "CD4+ Proliferating T", 
"CD4+ Proliferating T", "CD4+ Proliferating T", "CD4+ Proliferating T", 
"CD4+ Proliferating T", "CD4+ Proliferating T", "CD4+ Proliferating T", 
"CD4+ Proliferating T", "CD4+ Proliferating T", "CD4+ Proliferating T", 
"CD4+ Proliferating T", "CD4+ Proliferating T", "CD8+ Central Memory T", 
"CD8+ Central Memory T", "CD8+ Central Memory T", "CD8+ Central Memory T", 
"CD8+ Central Memory T", "CD8+ Central Memory T", "CD8+ Central Memory T", 
"CD8+ Central Memory T", "CD8+ Central Memory T", "CD8+ Central Memory T", 
"CD8+ Central Memory T", "CD8+ Central Memory T", "CD8+ Central Memory T", 
"CD8+ Central Memory T", "CD8+ Central Memory T", "CD8+ Central Memory T", 
"CD8+ Effector Memory T", "CD8+ Effector Memory T", "CD8+ Effector Memory T", 
"CD8+ Effector Memory T", "CD8+ Effector Memory T", "CD8+ Effector Memory T", 
"CD8+ Effector Memory T", "CD8+ Effector Memory T", "CD8+ Effector Memory T", 
"CD8+ Effector Memory T", "CD8+ Effector Memory T", "CD8+ Effector Memory T", 
"CD8+ Effector Memory T", "CD8+ Effector Memory T", "CD8+ Effector Memory T", 
"CD8+ Effector Memory T", "CD8+ Naive T", "CD8+ Naive T", "CD8+ Naive T", 
"CD8+ Naive T", "CD8+ Naive T", "CD8+ Naive T", "CD8+ Naive T", 
"CD8+ Naive T", "CD8+ Naive T", "CD8+ Naive T", "CD8+ Naive T", 
"CD8+ Naive T", "CD8+ Naive T", "CD8+ Naive T", "CD8+ Naive T", 
"CD8+ Naive T", "CD8+ Proliferating T", "CD8+ Proliferating T", 
"CD8+ Proliferating T", "CD8+ Proliferating T", "CD8+ Proliferating T", 
"CD8+ Proliferating T", "CD8+ Proliferating T", "CD8+ Proliferating T", 
"CD8+ Proliferating T", "CD8+ Proliferating T", "CD8+ Proliferating T", 
"CD8+ Proliferating T", "CD8+ Proliferating T", "CD8+ Proliferating T", 
"CD8+ Proliferating T", "CD8+ Proliferating T", "Double-negative T", 
"Double-negative T", "Double-negative T", "Double-negative T", 
"Double-negative T", "Double-negative T", "Double-negative T", 
"Double-negative T", "Double-negative T", "Double-negative T", 
"Double-negative T", "Double-negative T", "Double-negative T", 
"Double-negative T", "Double-negative T", "Double-negative T", 
"gamma-delta T", "gamma-delta T", "gamma-delta T", "gamma-delta T", 
"gamma-delta T", "gamma-delta T", "gamma-delta T", "gamma-delta T", 
"gamma-delta T", "gamma-delta T", "gamma-delta T", "gamma-delta T", 
"gamma-delta T", "gamma-delta T", "gamma-delta T", "gamma-delta T", 
"Regulatory T", "Regulatory T", "Regulatory T", "Regulatory T", 
"Regulatory T", "Regulatory T", "Regulatory T", "Regulatory T", 
"Regulatory T", "Regulatory T", "Regulatory T", "Regulatory T", 
"Regulatory T", "Regulatory T", "Regulatory T", "Regulatory T"
), percent = c(25.7, 1.9, 3, 14.9, 10.8, 27.3, 28.8, 26.9, 25.3, 
1.5, 11.7, 28.7, 30.5, 1.1, 8.4, 25.2, 7.8, 22.6, 10, 11.4, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2.7, 10, 8.1, 1.7, 25, 6.2, 
1.3, 8, 1.9, 24, 30, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 14, 6.6, 14.6, 14.6, 1.3, 
0.8, 6.8, 6.5, 15.4, 16.2, 0.7, 6, 15.6, 0.9, 17.1, 17.1, 37.1, 
34, 40.5, 45.1, 27, 43.8, 47.8, 35.2, 38.5, 38.2, 35.7, 36.2, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 12.2, 4.9, 2, 13.9, 7.7, 32.1, 23.3, 3.2, 7.8, 20, 
21.7, 27, 20, 24, 1.6, 17.5, 31.9, 31.8, 6.7, 33.1, 22.4, 6.7, 
36.1, 16.1, 35.6, 34.1, 2.2, 19.6, 39.3, 40.3, 3.5, 12.4, 6.8, 
9.2, 20.3, 20.7, 21.1, 20.8, 8.3, 0.9, 18.4, 21.2, 9.8, 20.2, 
1.3, 0.8, 17.4, 1.1, 33.7, 36.8, 44.3, 43.6, 42, 27, 35.1, 47, 
45.6, 33.3, 41, 38.2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.7, 0.9, 20, 14.4, 15, 2.9, 
5.5, 6.7, 15.7, 10, 0.6, 0.9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5.3, 35.7, 21.4, 32.7, 
41.4, 4.7, 39.4, 16, 12.6, 42.5, 32.9, 7.3, 16.7, 32.5, 2.5, 
30.7, 21.8, 17.2, 1.1, 7.7, 7, 7.7, 1.3, 14.5, 9.9, 19.9, 20, 
2.5, 17.1, 20, 9.6, 20.3), color = c("#F2F4F5", "#A7CFE3", "#A7CFE3", 
"#A7CFE3", "#BEDAE8", "#F6EBE6", "#F6E4DC", "#F6ECE7", "#F6EBE7", 
"#A7CFE3", "#A7CFE3", "#F6F1EF", "#F6E1D8", "#A7CFE3", "#A7CFE3", 
"#F6F3F1", "#F2F4F5", "#F6E0D7", "#F6F5F4", "#F6F6F6", "#D0E3ED", 
"#D0E3ED", "#D0E3ED", "#D0E3ED", "#D0E3ED", "#D0E3ED", "#D0E3ED", 
"#D0E3ED", "#D0E3ED", "#D0E3ED", "#D0E3ED", "#D0E3ED", "#D0E3ED", 
"#E3EDF2", "#D0E3ED", "#D0E3ED", "#F5CBB9", "#D0E3ED", "#D0E3ED", 
"#D0E3ED", "#D0E3ED", "#F5C8B5", "#CA0020", "#F5D2C3", "#D0E3ED", 
"#D0E3ED", "#D0E3ED", "#D0E3ED", "#F6F3F2", "#D0E3ED", "#F6F4F3", 
"#D0E3ED", "#D0E3ED", "#D0E3ED", "#D0E3ED", "#D0E3ED", "#F6F3F2", 
"#F6F1EE", "#D0E3ED", "#D0E3ED", "#F6F4F3", "#D0E3ED", "#F6F2F1", 
"#F6F0EE", "#F0F3F5", "#CEE2EC", "#F6F1EE", "#F5D0C0", "#BCDAE8", 
"#F5C8B4", "#F4BFA7", "#B1D4E5", "#F6DED4", "#C2DDEA", "#F2F4F5", 
"#F6F2F0", "#82BBD8", "#82BBD8", "#82BBD8", "#82BBD8", "#D1E4ED", 
"#A9D0E3", "#A9D0E3", "#A9D0E3", "#A9D0E3", "#F5C1AB", "#F5C3AC", 
"#A9D0E3", "#CEE3ED", "#F2F4F5", "#F5D4C5", "#F6ECE8", "#F6E8E2", 
"#F6EAE5", "#A9D0E3", "#F6EEEB", "#F5CAB7", "#F5CFBF", "#3B91C1", 
"#F5D4C5", "#90C4DD", "#2483BA", "#F5C1AA", "#A1CCE1", "#F5CCBA", 
"#F5D2C2", "#2483BA", "#A8CFE3", "#F4BFA8", "#F3A481", "#2483BA", 
"#54A0C9", "#ACD2E4", "#ACD2E4", "#F0F3F5", "#F6F3F2", "#F4F5F6", 
"#F6F0ED", "#ACD2E4", "#ACD2E4", "#EEF2F4", "#F6E0D6", "#C7DFEB", 
"#EEF2F4", "#ACD2E4", "#ACD2E4", "#E2ECF1", "#ACD2E4", "#DAE8EF", 
"#F6E7E0", "#F6E1D8", "#F5D4C6", "#F5C2AC", "#9ECBE1", "#A8CFE3", 
"#F5D4C5", "#F5C2AC", "#78B5D5", "#F5D4C6", "#F1F4F5", "#2181B9", 
"#2181B9", "#2181B9", "#2181B9", "#D0E3ED", "#D0E3ED", "#F5D5C7", 
"#F6E5DD", "#F6F6F6", "#D0E3ED", "#D0E3ED", "#E8EFF3", "#F4A684", 
"#F6F3F2", "#D0E3ED", "#D0E3ED", "#D0E3ED", "#D0E3ED", "#D0E3ED", 
"#D0E3ED", "#0571B0", "#F3A280", "#B1D4E5", "#F6EDE9", "#F09578", 
"#0571B0", "#F4B599", "#9BC9E0", "#4295C4", "#F0987A", "#EF9578", 
"#3C92C2", "#7FB9D7", "#F5C3AC", "#0571B0", "#F4BDA4", "#F0F3F5", 
"#E8EFF3", "#C1DCE9", "#DBE9F0", "#C1DCE9", "#C1DCE9", "#C1DCE9", 
"#E8EFF3", "#C1DCE9", "#F6EAE4", "#F6E2D9", "#C1DCE9", "#E9F0F3", 
"#F0F3F5", "#C1DCE9", "#F1F4F5")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-192L))

# separate by treatments for each trace to be plotted.
set1 = df_test %>% dplyr::filter(treatment %in% "untreated")
set2 = df_test %>% dplyr::filter(treatment %in% "treat_1")
set3 = df_test %>% dplyr::filter(treatment %in% "treat_2")
set4 = df_test %>% dplyr::filter(treatment %in% "treat_3")

# set up order of x and y axis variables
xform <- list(categoryorder = "array", categoryarray = c("Donor-1-Unstim", "Donor-2-Unstim", "Donor-3-Unstim","Donor-4-Unstim", 
                                                         "Donor-1-treat_1", "Donor-2-treat_1", "Donor-3-treat_1","Donor-4-treat_1",
                                                         "Donor-1-treat_2", "Donor-2-treat_2", "Donor-3-treat_2", "Donor-4-treat_2",
                                                         "Donor-1-treat_3", "Donor-2-treat_3", "Donor-3-treat_3", "Donor-4-treat_3"))
yform <- list(categoryorder = "array", categoryarray = c("CD4+ Naive T", "CD4+ Central Memory T", "CD4+ Effector Memory T", "CD4+ Proliferating T","CD4+ Cytotoxic T", "Regulatory T", "CD8+ Naive T", "CD8+ Central Memory T", "CD8+ Effector Memory T", "CD8+ Proliferating T", "Double-negative T", "gamma-delta T"))

# figure plotting
markers <- list(size = ~percent, colorscale="RdBu", colorbar = list(title = "Signature Score", len = 0.4, y = 0.1),
                line = list(color = ~score, colorscale="RdBu", width = 2), showscale = TRUE)

fig <- plot_ly() %>%
  add_trace(data = set1, x =~samples, y=~celltype, name =  "Untreated",
            type = 'scatter', 
            mode = 'markers',
            text = ~paste("% : ", round(percent, 2) , "<br>Score: ", round(score, 3)),
            hoverinfo = "text",
            color = ~score,
            colors = ~color,
            marker = markers) %>% 
  add_trace(data = set2, x =~samples, y=~celltype, name =  "treat_1",
            type = 'scatter', 
            mode = 'markers',
            text = ~paste("% : ", round(percent, 2) , "<br>Score: ", round(score, 3)),
            hoverinfo = "text",
            color = ~score,
            colors = ~color,
            marker = markers) %>%
  add_trace(data = set3, x =~samples, y=~celltype, name =  "treat_2",
            type = 'scatter', 
            mode = 'markers',
            text = ~paste("% : ", round(percent, 2) , "<br>Score: ", round(score, 3)),
            hoverinfo = "text",
            color = ~score,
            colors = ~color,
            marker = markers) %>%
  add_trace(data = set4, x =~samples, y=~celltype, name =  "treat_3",
            type = 'scatter', 
            mode = 'markers',
            text = ~paste("% : ", round(percent, 2) , "<br>Score: ", round(score, 3)),
            hoverinfo = "text",
            color = ~score,
            colors = ~color,
            marker = markers) %>% 
  layout(xaxis = xform, yaxis = yform)
  

fig
```

Generates this figure:

[image]