# In R highcharter package add character vector as y-Axis is not working

Tags: r, highcharts, r-highcharter

Ive been trying to create this simple chart using highcharter packaga in R but its not working.

I dont know If I have to change the class of object to factor.

Any help?

```
library(gapminder)
library(highcharter)
df <- gapminder::gapminder %>%
  filter(continent == 'Americas', year == 2007)

df%>%

  hchart(
    'scatter',
    names = 'SQUADS',
    hcaes(y = country,
          x = factor(lifeExp)
    ),
    color = '#B55C64'
    # colorByPoint = TRUE
  ) %>%

  hc_yAxis(

    type = 'category',
    categories = df$country,
    tickAmount = 20,
    gridLineWidth = 0.5,
    gridLineColor = 'gray',
    gridLineDashStyle = "longdash",


    title = list(text = ''))
```

Comment: Could you please share some sample data that you would like to display there? Or is it best to send this demo in JS? https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/j26zu8pd/ Then I'll be able to help you better with this example.

Comment: @madepiet thanks a lot for your time. I edited the question. The data belongs to gapminder package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49034106/how-to-produce-scatterplot-with-a-factor-as-y-in-highcharter), you could use the `levels` of your factor column and make the index of your column to 0 like this:

```r
library(highcharter)
library(dplyr)
df <- gapminder::gapminder %>%
  filter(continent == 'Americas', year == 2007)

your_ylabels = levels(df$country)

df %>%
  hchart('scatter',
         hcaes(x = lifeExp, y = as.numeric(country) - 1)) %>%
  hc_yAxis(categories = your_ylabels)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-03-17 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>